# Sorting an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following data structure and I'm stuck on a way to sorting all variants from all items in ascending order based on price.

Ideally I need a way to find the lowest price of any item variant while still having access to the variant's parent.

```
var items = [
{
    "id" : 1 ,
    "name" : "name1",
    "variations" : [
        {
            "subId" : 1000011,
            "subName" : "name1a",
            "price" : 19.99
        },
        {
            "subId" : 1000012,
            "subName" : "name1b",
            "price" : 53.21
        },
        {
            "subId" : 1000013,
            "subName" : "name1c",
            "price" : 9.49

        }
    ]

},
{
    "id" : 2, 
    "name" : "name2",
    "variations" : [
        {
            "subId" : 1000021,
            "subName" : "name2a",
            "price" : 99.29
        },
        {
            "subId" : 1000022,
            "subName" : "name2b",
            "price" : 104.99
        },
        {
            "subId" : 1000023,
            "subName" : "name2c",
            "price" : 38.00

        }
    ]

}

];
```

Comment: Just a point of education here: This has *nothing* to do with JSON. What you have is an array of objects.  JSON is an interchange and storage format that just looks a lot like JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code in order to do it:

```
items.forEach(function(item){
  var variations = item.variations.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.price - a.price;
  });
  console.log(variations);
});
```

This function is going to be called for every item inside of the `items` array. If you want to order only the first, or second or `n` item in the items array you need to use something like:

```
var variations = items[0].variations.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.price - a.price;
});
console.log(variations);
```

Where `items[0]` represents the item you want to order.

As you can see:

```
function(a, b){
  return b.price - a.price;
}
```

Is the function that orders the final result of the every array `item` from the `items` array. Using [the `sort` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You can read more about how the compare function works to sort the items of an array.

> the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/sonejibopo/edit?js,console):

```
var sortedByPrice = items.map(function(item) {
  item.variations.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
  });

  return item;
});

console.log(sortedByprice);
```

Just map through them and sort based on the variation's price.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors / mistypes in your .json. after fix you can use something like this:

```
var items = [
{
    "id" : 1 ,
    "name" : "name1",
    "variations" : [
        {
            "subId" : 1000011,
            "subName" : "name1a",
            "price" : 19.99
        },
        {
          "subId" : 1000012,
            "subName" : "name1b",
            "price" : 53.21
        },
        {
          "subId" : 1000013,
            "subName" : "name1c",
            "price" : 9.49

        }
    ]

},
{
    "id" : 2, 
    "name" : "name2",
    "variations" : [
        {
            "subId" : 1000021,
            "subName" : "name2a",
            "price" : 99.29
        },
        {
          "subId" : 1000022,
            "subName" : "name2b",
            "price" : 104.99
        },
        {
          "subId" : 1000023,
            "subName" : "name2c",
            "price" : 38.00

        }
    ]

}

];
items;

items.sort(function(a,b){
  var mina=a.variations.sort(function(x,y){
       return x.price - y.price;
     })[0].price; //find minimal price in 1st variations
  var minb=b.variations.sort(function(x,y){
       return x.price - y.price;
    })[0].price; // in 2nd variations
return mina - minb; //what compare returns 
});
```

### Update 1

If you want more structural solution use this:

```
function minProp(arr, prop){
  return arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[prop] - b[prop];
  })[0][prop];
}

items.sort(function(a,b){
  var mina = minProp(a.variations,'price');
  var minb = minProp(b.variations,'price');
return mina-minb;  
});
```

More structure may be invoked.